# How can I order the months chronologically in ggplot2 short of writing the months out?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot count v/s month

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=month, y=count,group=region)) +
    geom_line(data=mcount[mcount$region == "West coast", ],colour="black",stat="identity", position="dodge")+
     geom_point(data=mcount[mcount$region == "West coast", ],colour="black", size=2, shape=21, fill="white")+
     theme_bw()+
     theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black")) +
     guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))+
     ggsave("test.png",width=6, height=4,dpi=300)
```

[image]

But I want to order the months chronologically from Jan to Dec. How can I do this short of writing all the months out?

```
dat <- data.table::data.table(
  region = factor(
    rep(
      c(
        "Appalachians", "Mississippi valley", "Front range", "Flash flood alley",
        "Arizona", "West coast", "Arizona", "Front range"
      ),
      c(12L, 12L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 2L, 6L)
    ),
    levels = c(
      "West coast", "Arizona", "Front range", "Flash flood alley",
      "Mississippi valley", "Appalachians"
    )
  ),
  month = factor(
    c(
      "Apr", "Dec", "Oct", "Mar", "May", "Jul", "Sep", "Jun", "Nov", "Aug", "Jan",
      "Feb", "Apr", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "May", "Dec", "Nov", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
      "Oct", "Sep", "Jun", "Aug", "May", "Apr", "Jul", "Sep", "Mar", "Jul", "Jun",
      "Dec", "Apr", "Sep", "May", "Oct", "Jan", "Feb", "Nov", "Aug", "Dec", "Sep",
      "Oct", "Jul", "Feb", "Jan", "Aug", "Nov", "Mar", "Apr", "Jan", "Mar", "Dec",
      "Apr", "Feb", "Nov", "Oct", "Jun", "May", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "May", "Jun",
      "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ),
    levels = c("Apr", "Dec", "Oct", "Mar", "May", "Jul", "Sep", "Jun", "Nov", "Aug", "Jan", "Feb")
  ),
  count = c(
    566, 545, 427, 751, 357, 399, 568, 433, 454, 347, 511, 251, 267, 207, 167,
    142, 417, 109, 117, 373, 207, 130, 125, 145, 7, 14, 2, 2, 7, 3, 107, 74, 135,
    48, 80, 53, 117, 125, 59, 53, 103, 30, 21, 18, 8, 22, 26, 37, 20, 5, 11, 1,
    96, 29, 109, 8, 33, 53, 6, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  )
)
```

Comment: are you asking how to take your current graph and organize it chronologically, or have your labels in chronological order?

Comment: On a side note, are you adamant on using ggplot2 for this? Have you looked at using dygraphs with dates?



All you need to do is convert your month column to a date type.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Have never used anything besides ggplot2. Happy to learn useful libraries. Feel free to add. Thank you.

Comment: I HIGHLY suggest using dyraphs for this exact issue.

https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

You need to know how to create time series objects, but this isn't an issue.

Comment: This seems like a minor issue to change your whole approach. It has a very simple fix.

Comment: Gregor, I'm just making a suggestion if the OP would like to approach this differently in the future.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Thanks. Looks interesting and I'll take a look at it for a different project.

Comment: I would also point out that, if you need a time series object to use dygraphs, then "this exact issue" is unchanged. You need to know how to order your character/factor variable in non-alphabetical order to get a time-series object with the correct ordering. Dygraphs look great, I'm a big fan of interactive graphics - I just think they are completely tangential to the issue in this question.

Comment: @Gregor Yes. I realized it. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the built-in `month.name` or `month.abb` variable to specify the levels of your factor in the correct order. In this case, you have abbreviations so `month.abb` is appropriate.

```
your_data$month = factor(your_data$month, levels = month.abb)
```

I think creating the factor in the correct order is the best way, but you can also just order the axis using the `limits` argument of the discrete scale (see `?discrete_scale` for more info).

```
+ scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)
```

### Locales

If you are in a non-English locale, you can construct your own month name constants with a little date formatting (basically stolen from Brian Ripley [in this R-Help thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-May/051503.html)):

```
 month.name.loc = format(ISOdate(2004, 1:12, 1), "%B")
 month.abb.loc  = format(ISOdate(2004, 1:12, 1), "%b")
```

If you want to use month names/abbreviations from a different locale than you're in, the `withr` package is useful.

Comment: didn't know about these variables, nice +1.

Comment: This is so good to know, and was totally invisible to me before. Thanks! One thing to notice: `month.abb` seems to only recognize month names in English only. It would be so good if they matched the locale...